# Symfony3 installation with Composer exception "$id must be a string or an alias object"

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony

I have a problem with the installation of Symfony3 with composer, I followed the steps on the official web site but I have got the problem below and I can't run the symfony application

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]

     $id must be a string, or an Alias object.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please include the steps (commands?) you've taken which led to the aforementioned problem...